# Super basic example of file upload with MVC 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, file-upload

Looking for an extremely straight-forward, basic tutorial on how to do file upload using MVC 2.0, from how to do the form, the controller, the save as, routing, and any IO stuff.

The form is simply a browse button, and, the files would be uploaded to "e:\data" folder.

Please help!  Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [File upload in MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605766/file-upload-in-mvc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [Phil Haack's example](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx) to be very helpful when I did this.